# How to interact with python terminal in front end

Tags: python, reactjs, django, telethon, react-fullstack

I'm trying to convert a python project Im working on into a website. I was going to write it in Django/React.
The project uses telethon to get messages from telegram, and to start the session, an interactive program runs in the python terminal. Ex:

```
Client.start()
##enter phone number:
##enter passcode we sent:
##enter 2fa password:
```

How would I be able to interact with this from the frontend?